# ajax toolkit error uploading first website to a new hosting server

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webserver

my hosting services company is using  parallels plesk panel 9.5

after working fine in my local iis on windows 7

as it's the **first time** i am uploading a website there , what could be the problem with this error

*Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

if its important , at the bottom of the page theres a message

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

i realize that i have no access to registry and as its not something i could think i should take to consideration , i should think that's only a general message as the company is well established firm

update

this is the application , i don't use a private server online
`parallels plesk panel 9.5`

[image: if you cant read download it to your pc]

iis is on **MY** dev pc = **local** (while working on project)  and its **ok**!

problem with **uploaded** website -  when it's online =  on server of hoseting service company

look at it in picture that is to your comment : "*go to advance settings in application pool change identity to network service. let me know any update.* "

thanks

Comment: Check if you use the correct version of AjaxControlToolkit and download the latest version. Eg, what asp.net version the server runs, and is 32 or 64 bit ? Is the same with your computer ?

Comment: @Aristos
how could i know which server , look i have managed to load another page for test , the test does not include an ajax assembly directive so it does work with .net 4.0 , i was working with ajaxToolkit 3.038 i now upgraded to 4 , no change

Comment: Check AjaxControlToolkit.dll in your bin folder

Comment: @chamara what did you mean, @ chamara, i don't understand (but of course it's in `bin` folder) , i said .. not only that i've checked it, i've upgraded `AjaxToolkit.dll`, and it didn't matter, cause at all times my local site +server functioned , but as soon as i upload it gives that same error no matter what version,   also deleted directory and redployed it

Comment: ok. i guess you are using .net 4.0 .one more suggestion. check the iis application pool basic settings. it should set to use .net version 4.0. if that's ok try the following. go to advance settings in application pool change identity to network service. let me know any update.

Comment: @chamara see my update , there is no such thing , do you know plesk?

Comment: i was referring to iis with my previous comment. i'm pretty much sure plesk support service can help you. create a support ticket. if it's working in your local machine issue might be with the service provider. They might have installed an older version of Ajaxtoolkit on the server. so that you might get the error. you should contact the support staff with your toolkit version details.

Comment: @chamara thanks, seems that my tries with deleting and recreation of directory-physical + virtual settings <--especially the virtual settings was incorrect , I've explained it in my answer for future comers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a problem with virtual directories setting, and permissions to write /execute scripts

when you're using plesk you should know how to set proprties for each virtual directory within the properties of the domain's virtual directories section , properties .